# Different definition of uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I'm reading Tao's *An introduction to measure theory*.And the definition of uniform integrability in this book is

$(X,{\mathfrak  {M}},\mu)$ is a measure space(not necessarily finite). A sequence $f_n:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of absolutely Integrable functions is said to be *uniformly Integrable if the following three statements hold*

1.(Uniform bound on $L^1$ normal) One has $\sup_n\|f_n\|_{L^1(\mu)}=\sup_n\int_{X}|f_n|d\mu <+\infty$.

2.(No escape to vertical infinity) One has $\sup_n\int_{|f_n|\ge M}|f_n|d\mu\xrightarrow{M\rightarrow\infty} 0$.

3.(No escape to width infinity) One has $\sup_n\int_{|f_n|\le\delta}|f_n|d\mu\xrightarrow{\delta\rightarrow0} 0$.

However, the definition of uniform integrability in Wikipedia is

> Let $(X,{\mathfrak  {M}},\mu ) $ be a positive measure space. A set ${\displaystyle \Phi \subset L^{1}(\mu )}$ is called uniformly integrable if to each ${\displaystyle \varepsilon >0} $  there corresponds a ${\displaystyle \delta >0}$  such that
> ${\displaystyle \int _{E}|f|\,d\mu <\varepsilon }
> $ whenever ${\displaystyle f\in \Phi }$ and ${\displaystyle \mu (E)<\delta .}$

Tao leaves the equivalence of this two definitions when $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is finite(namely $\mu(X)<+\infty$) as an exercise, and I've prove it. But I can't prove the equivalence of them when $\mu(X)=+\infty$. Can anyone prove or disprove it?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:I've also prove that the first definition implies the second one(which is also an exercise in Tao's book). So the problem becomes whether the second one implies the first one.

Comment: Is $X$ sigma finite?

Comment: @Jacky Chong:No, it's not mentioned in the book.

Comment: @Rixinner: The Wiki page on [uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) is now updated. It has more definitions of uniform integrability related to the classic notion introduced by Hunt. Interestingly enough, the German [wiki article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichgradige_Integrierbarkeit) has been more complete than the English one by far. The definition in Tao's book is a curios definition as it is not equivalent to Hunt's: Hun't implies Tao's but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in Wikipedia is to weak to imply 1), 2) and 3). Consider $\mathbb  N$ with power set and the counting measure. Any family of functions satisfies the Wikipedia  condition since $\mu (E) <1$ implies that $E$ is the empty set. You can easily write down a family of functions each of which satsifies the condition $\|f||_1=\sum |f(n) |<\infty$ but the norms are not bounded when$f$ varies over the family. [I will write down an explicit example if you ask for it].

Comment: Thanks! I've got what you mean.