# Reconciling two definitions of uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Take a family $F$ of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, then $F$ is uniformly integrable if:

**Definition 1 (Royden):** For each $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $f\in F$, if a Borel set $I$ is such that $\lambda(I)<\delta$ (Lebesgue measure), then $\int_I |f|<\epsilon$.

**Definition 2 (Billingsley):** The following holds uniformly: $\lim_{a\to\infty}\sup_n \int_{|f|\geq a} |f| =0$.

I can easily see how definition 1 yields definition 2, but have trouble seeing the reverse direction. My guess is we look at $(-\infty, -a]\cup [a,\infty)$ to construct $\delta$ as responding to $\epsilon$, but unsure on the exact approach.

*Comments and questions(that I'll leave here but personally expand upon later): Here is a definition of tightness (from my course notes) for random variables on standard $\mathbb{P}$-spaces:*

- *A family of random variables $\{Y_\alpha| \alpha\in \mathcal{S}\}$ is tight if for $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact $K$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y_\alpha \notin K)<\epsilon$ for any $\alpha$. How does this tie into uniform integrability?*
  *- Tightness of a family of measures: $\mu_n(\{x||x|>u\})\to 0$ as $u\to\infty$*
- *Tightness of a family of functions suggest, more or less, that such functions "don't escape to infinity", or rather that their "escape to infinity" is arbitrarily small and they can therefore be sufficiently approximated on a set $E$ of finite measure.*
- *Example of not tight (but uniformly integrable) functions: $f_n = \mathbb{X}_{[n,n+1]}$*
- *Example of not uniformly integrable (but tight) functions: $f_n = n \mathbb{X}_{[0,1/n]}$*
- *From this, we see that tightness is a "horizontal" constraint. See Royden's Vitali Convergence Theorem, finite and general cases. On the other hand, uniform integrability is a "vertical" constraint.*
- *Next question: what is the relation between the aforementioned concepts and the $L^p$ spaces? In particular, we know that perhaps due to non-tightness, we may see functions that converge pointwise in $L^1$ to a $f$, but not weakly to it in $L^1$.*

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4437079/121671)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $a$ such that $\sup_f\int_{|f|>a} |f|<\epsilon$. Then for any $I$,
$$ \int_I |f| \le \int_{|f|>a} |f| + \int_{(|f|\le a) \cap I} |f| < \epsilon + a \lambda(I)$$
So if we pick $\delta = \epsilon/a$ we get for $I$ with $\lambda(I)<\delta$ that $\sup_f\int_{I} |f|\le2\epsilon$, QED.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Calvin Khor  Thanks for your explanation but I still need help understanding it if you don't mind. I understand that without the $\cap{I}$, then it would just be $ \lt \epsilon$. But, when you put the $\cap$ there, does that mean that the integral is over the intersection of the two sets or that the integral is over both of the sets $|f| \le a$ and $I$. Thanks and I  really appreciate your help.

Comment: Also, is the $n$ in Billingsley's definition, just a typo ? That confused me also. Thanks again.

Comment: @markleeds yes, the intersection symbol means the integral is over the intersection of the sets. It is simply the Lebesgue integral $\int_A |f|$ with  $A= \{x \in \mathbb R : |f(x)|\le a \} \cap I$. And the $\sup_n$ I guess should be $\sup_{f \in F}$ but I didn't check Billingsley

Comment: Hi Calvin: Thanks for your help. But that's what confuses me.  If it's the interesction, then that set is smaller than just $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \le a\}$, so how can one put the $\epsilon$ on the other side ? Thanks and apologies for so many questions.

Comment: @markleeds $$\int_I |f| = \int_{ (|f|\le a)\cap I} |f| + \int_{(|f|>a) \cap I} |f| \le \int_{ (|f|\le a)\cap I} |f| + \int_{|f|>a } |f|$$ and $$\int_{(|f|\le a)\cap I} |f| \le\int_{(|f|\le a)\cap I} a \le \int_I a = a\lambda(I)$$

Comment: @Calvin Khor: It makes sense to my brain now. And it's much appreciated.